# How do I loop through keyboard interrupt whenever the user presses ctrl+c multiple times in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python3 on android 6 (termux linux emulator) and python works great, but I want to create a login everytime termux starts up by adding this program to ~/.bashrc, the problem is when I ask the user for the password, and they enter ctrl-c, the program will be alerted that they tried to bypass security, and force them to wait for 5 minutes before trying again. So my question is how can I loop the KeyboardInterrupt so while they are waiting 5 minutes and they press ctrl-c again it will make them wait 10 minutes, 15 minutes (up by 5) etc and so forth, so they cant bypass the waiting time?

Comment: Why make a user wait for so long instead of just asking for password once again after e.g. 1 second? I'd be much more concerned about users supplying incorrect passwords as fast as possible; that could be a brute-force attempt. I'd only accept a password, correct or not, once a second the first 10 times, then e.g. once  a 5 seconds, and would treat Ctrl+C as an incorrect password.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that sounds better, than making the user wait it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the user 9000, but if you really want to do this, my solution would be the following:

```
import time

password_check_passed = False
while not password_check_passed:
    try:
        password_check_passed = check_password()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("You are required to authenticate yourself. You've received a cooldown of 5 minutes.")
        end_of_punishment = time.time() + 5*60   # now + 5 minutes
        while time.time() < end_of_punishment:
            try:
                # attempt to sleep until the end of the punitive timeout
                time.sleep(end_of_punishment - time.time())
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("Still not getting it? 5 more minutes!")
                end_of_punishment += 5*60
```

The `check_password` function would return a boolean indicating that it succeeded and print out any instructions for authentication.

While there is technically a possibility to send two interrupts fast enough for the second one to occur before the inner `try` clause, it is very small and I wouldn't worry about it.

What you should be more worried about is that this makes termination of your program much more difficult.

Comment: That was very helpful! Thank you, I never thought of doing it that way